# Highcharts solidgauge in another chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm having a trouble adding solidgauge type of chart on a column chart. Combinations section demo on highcharts website contains examples of line+column+pie types but changing the type to 'solidgauge' gives an error.
Can someone provide an example or explanation of how to do it?
Or maybe it can't be done?

code:

```
var weeks = [1,2,3,4],
    plan_2g = [5,6,3,4],
    install_2g = [5,6,4,3],
    plan_3g = [5,4,3,2],
    install_3g = [4,3,2,1]

$('#container').highcharts({

            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                zoomType: 'y'
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Main title'
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: weeks
            },

            yAxis: {
                allowDecimals: false,
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'RBS-s'
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                shared:true
            },
            plotOptions : {
                column: {
                    grouping: false,
                    shadow: false,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: '2G Plan',
                data: plan_2g,
                color: 'rgb(124, 181, 236)',

                pointPadding: 0.3,
                pointPlacement: -0.3
            }, {
                name: '2G Install',
                data: install_2g,
                color: 'rgb(82, 119, 154)',

                pointPadding: 0.4,
                pointPlacement: -0.3
            }, {
                name: '3G Plan',
                data: plan_3g,
                color: 'rgb(134, 216, 115)',

                pointPadding: 0.3,
                pointPlacement: 0
            }, {
                name: '3G Install',
                data: install_3g,
                color: 'rgb(95, 154, 82)',

                pointPadding: 0.4,
                pointPlacement: 0
            }
            ],
            exporting: {
                sourceWidth: 1000,
                sourceHeight: 400,
                scale: 1,
                chartOptions: {
                    subtitle: null
                }
        }
        });
```

JSFiddle
    http://jsfiddle.net/5vomwh1j/

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you included all required files, like highcharts-more.js and solid-gauge.js? Also, create jsFiddle to show us what have you tried.

Comment: i added jfiddle and code to original post. what i want is to add the same kind of solidgauge ( http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-solid ) to this chart

Comment: i might be wrong ... but I think you will have to make multiple gauges

Comment: sorry I dont understand what do you mean bu multiple gauges

Comment: i only need 1 for working example. just a simple 180 degrees gauge, no interval data.

Comment: It looks like a bug - reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3947). Thanks!